# LOGO image not rendered within Header in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on http://companies.ur-nl.com/ seems Logo *(its  `H1`)* image in header is not rendered in IE7, it works within FF and other browsers, Please help me out of this

HTML

```
    <div id='logo'>
      <h1>
         <a href='/' title='Some Text HERE'>
           Some Text HERE
         </a>
      </h1>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
#logo a {
    background: url("http://companies.ur-nl.com/assets/logo_image_name.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 62px;
    margin: 35px 0 0;
    text-indent: -100000px;
    width: 195px;
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to your question.

Comment: @m90 just updated my question

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a well known text-indent bug for IE7, for example see [Text indent is not working in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888298/text-indent-is-not-working-in-ie7)

However, I could not get the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2978036/637889) for that question to work on your site. Instead you can remove the `text-indent` and replace with:

```
line-height: 0;
font-size: 0;
```

which seems to work nicely in the Chrome30, IE7 and IE9 browsers I tested with.

Source: [Solved: IE7 Negative Text-Indent CSS Bug](http://hanamidesign.com/blog/solved-ie7-text-indent-bug/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#logo a{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Define** This css

```
#logo a{
display:inline-block;  // remove this line
display:block;  // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because inline-block property isn't fully supported in IE7.

If for some reason you absolutely need the anchor inside the logo container to be an inline-block element for the major browsers, you can leave the `display: inline-block` rule and add a hack for IE7 like this:

```
#logo a {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: block;
}
```